# Google play subscription PlatformException with code 4 using revenuecat

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-services, revenuecat

I have problem with revenuecat. The application woking fin in the previous version. but when I tried testing the payment with new version the payments is not woking it gives me this error -- i'm using flutter

```
PlatformException(4, One or more of the arguments provided are invalid., {code: 4, message: One or more of the arguments provided are invalid., readableErrorCode: PurchaseInvalidError, readable_error_code: PurchaseInvalidError, underlyingErrorMessage: Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: . ErrorCode: DEVELOPER_ERROR., userCancelled: false}, null)
```

```dart
 PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(pk);
      if (purchaserInfo.entitlements.all[entitlements(pk)].isActive) {
        // Unlock that great "pro" content
        return true;
      }
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ? revenuecat is woking fin in IOS .

Comment: Can you share a snippet of how you’re calling the purchase function?

Comment: @Cesar i edit the question and i added the code

Comment: That looks good, but something is clearly wrong either on the Google's product side or on your sandbox account. To debug what's causing this I would create a new tester account to make sure it's not something on the user side, and second, I would create a new product and assign it to a new package to make sure it's not something related to the product.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might appear when you are trying to do in-app purchases in debug mode. Make sure your app is uploaded to Google Play Console because it will only work when you download the APK through the Play Store. For testing you can upload your APK as open testing and can assign testers email on it so that after approval he/she can download it and can test it.